# Android date range

Tags: java, android, date

I have 2 DatePickers which pick from date to date. And I need to take range of dates and put they in array.
So I have:

```
String s1 = "05.05.2014"
String s2 = "01.01.2015"
```

I need to make

```
String blablabla[] ={05.05.2014,06.05,2014,07.05.2014........01.01.2015}
```

Comment: For what do you need it? Isn't it easier to use the between (before and after) function?
Any why use strings? Why not dates?

Comment: I need that to send querry to API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with Java-Calender:

The key for this is adding 1 day to de date "s1", you can use `calendarFrom.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`

```
 String s1 = "05.05.2015";
 String s2 = "11.05.2015";
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
 Calendar calendarFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
 Calendar calendarUntil = Calendar.getInstance();

 calendarFrom.setTime(dateFormat.parse(s1));
 calendarUntil.setTime(dateFormat.parse(s2));
 while (calendarFrom.compareTo(calendarUntil) != 0) {
      System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendarFrom.getTime()));
      calendarFrom.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
 }
```

you can populate a List in the while loop and then handle it as you need...